# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: wireless usb

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, usb

I have an old wireless usb adapter found and plugged it in. (Edimax 11 mbps wireless mini adapter)

At first it seems to work, letting me choose wich wireless network. After typing the password for my network, it won't connect to it.

Ubuntu sas it's a wep encoded network.
In reality it's not.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
I've tried different drivers (even the windows) but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older wireless devices, manufactured before the introduction of WPA and WPA2, are generally not capable of doing WPA and WPA2 because the engineering that went into the chipset didn't provide for technologies that were unknown at the time. You can learn what the device will do with:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 auth
```

Of course, substitute your wireless interface if it's not wlan0. As WEP is quite insecure, I can't recommend you use the device if it doesn't authenticate with WPA2.

Comment: Thank you for the information!
The problem was that the adapter isn't capable to use wpa / wpa2. If I set my network to wep encryption, it works perfect. 

But then again, I don't want my network "secured" with wep. So I'm going to have buy a wpa2 wireless adapter.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Happy to help. I have a whole little museum of old technology hardware that's useless today!

Comment: I'm starting a little museum over here also, I guess :-) Bought a new usb wifi and it works well!